# How to cast a string into an identifier?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure and a table. In the table the name of the stored procedure is stored.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "hello" ()
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
  RAISE INFO 'Hello World!';
END;
$$;

CREATE TABLE "tasks"
(
  "id" integer,
  "name" text
);

INSERT INTO "tasks" ("id", "name") values (1, 'hello');

SELECT "name" from "tasks" where "id" = 1;
```

Now I want to execute the stored procedure, I have stored in the table.

```
CALL (SELECT "name" from "tasks" where "id" = 1) ();
```

How can this be done in Postgresql?

Comment: The search term you're looking for is "dynamic SQL".

Comment: @mustaccio When I search for [Dynamic SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/ecpg-dynamic.html) I get a description how to embed SQL in C. That is not what I want.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN

Comment: you can'-call that procedure that way see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=75d2a6cdeae9d94299597217615b70c5

Comment: @nbk It is possible to write a trampoline procedure: `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "proc" ("name" text) LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$ BEGIN EXECUTE format ('CALL %I ()', name); END; $$;`. This can be called with a string argument: `CALL proc ('hello');`. But it is not possible to pass the result of a sub-select to the function: `CALL proc ((select string_agg ("name", '') "name" from "tasks" where "id" = 1));`.

Comment: @ceving i can't  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=60691245de2e050d47613e8d140ac3b2 as i still don't understand what the user wants to do so i don't know if he wanst to pass hello or the complete select a string

Comment: @nbk My aim was to pass the result of the select to the procedure argument. But this does not seem to be possible as you can see in your fiddle: `cannot use subquery in CALL argument`.

Comment: my first fiddle shows how you can do it